# Keeping AngularJS controls states on back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button group that acts like a radio button group like the following:

```
<div class="col-md-10" data-ng-controller="type-controller">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="typeId" data-btn-radio="'1'">
            Option 1
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-success" ng-model="typeId" data-btn-radio="'2'">
            Option 2
        </label>
    </div>
    <input data-ng-model="typeId" name="typeId" type="hidden" ng-init="typeId = '1'" />
</div>
```

When I submit the form, the selected "radio" goes to the input hidden and it works as expected. The problem is if the user uses the back button. Let's say the user is on the page containing the code above, then the page navigates to another one, then if the user clicks the back button, the "state" of the button group is not kept. It resets making the UX not cool.

So how do I keep the value if the user leaves the page and comes back using the back button? I had this same problem in a different project that I could easily fix by triggering the functions that handle the "change" event using jQuery. I would just check the value of the hidden and set the control state accordingly. But now I'm not using jQuery anymore and I don't think I should manipulate the DOM from within my controller.

I'm using Angular and this site is not a SPA, using ajax to get the values is not the case here.